# I am getting the error in importing TILT from react. While working using Vite and react

Tags: reactjs, vite, tilt

The requested module '/node_modules/.vite/deps/react-tilt.js?t=1681239019006&v=59c21aef' does not provide an export named 'default

I tried reinstalling tilt again using npm still it didnt make any difference

Answer (score 4):

Try this

import { Tilt } from 'react-tilt'

Answer (score 2):

use react-parallax-tilt instead of react-tilt and remove --legacy-peer-deps from the command.
Also wherever you are using: import Tilt from "react-tilt", replace it with your new library like this: import Tilt from "react-parallax-tilt

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall the package with:

`npm uninstall react-tilt`

Then reinstalled it with:

`npm install react-tilt`

Then change the import to:

`import { Tilt } from "react-tilt";`

Answer (score 0):

jst install it will work perfectly:

```
npm install react-tilt react react-dom
```